# How can i get Adwords Manager ID when log in with Google Mail

Tags: php, api, google-ads-api

According to googleads api I have to set `customerId` in auth.ini file. Is there anyway to get Adwords Manager ID when login with Google Account so I can use 
`$user->SetClientCustomerId('Adwords-Manager-ID');` to get `client_accounts` through `GetAccountHierarchy`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `getCustomer` method of the [`CustomerService`](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/reference/latest/CustomerService) to retrieve a list of all customer IDs that the Google account whose OAuth2 grant you are using has access to.